# redis.py - sorting hashes by particular fields

Tags: python, sorting, hash, redis

I am using **redis.py** and was wondering how I can sort by a given field. I have read the documentation and attempted googling for examples, but haven't found anyhting.

In this case, I have a list of times and the corresponding temperatures. For a given range of 'time', say 1000 to 1100, I'd return the highest values for temp' for a given range of times, assigning it to the variable **hightemp**. Likewise, I would like to do it with **lowtemp** too.

**Is it possible to do this within redis, as opposed to translating everything back into memory again, as would be the case if I sorted using python**

```
import redis
red = redis.Redis()

red.hmset('temperature', {'time':900, 'temp':123})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':930, 'temp':123})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':1000, 'temp':121})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':1030, 'temp':125})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':1100, 'temp':126})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':1130, 'temp':127})
red.hmset('temperature', {'time':1200, 'temp':128})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After pondering this for a while, I have to say it's tricky. The best solution I can come up with is this: Store the data in a [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands/#sorted_set), with `time` as score and `time:temperature` as value (to keep the values unique). Then you use [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore) to get the wanted subset:

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd temperature 1000 1000:123
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd temperature 1050 1050:122
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zadd temperature 1100 1100:125
(integer) 1
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> zrangebyscore temperature 1000 1100
1) "1000:123"
2) "1050:122"
3) "1100:125"
redis 127.0.0.1:6379>
```

These values, however, will be sorted on the score, i.e. the temperature. So you will have to sort the subset in the client instead:

```
# Result from Redis
result = ['1000:123', '1050:122', '1100:125']
# Weed out the temperatures
temperatures = [int(x.split(':')[1]) for x in result]
# Get max and min temperatures
max_temp, min_temp = max(temperatures), min(temperatures)
```

It's not super pretty, but it should work. What Lloyd Moore says in his answer is true, and you can sort by fields in hashes, but the [SORT](http://redis.io/commands/sort) command won't let you select a subset easily. I will update this answer if I think of a better solution, or we'll just hope for a healthy discussion in the comments!

**Edit:** Changed from python `sort()` to `max`/`min` after Didier Speza's advice.

Comment: To calculate temperature min and max, a proper sort is not needed. A simple O(n) scan in Python on the temperatures list is a bit better: maxt, mint = max(temperatures), min(temperatures)

Comment: Thanks! I was originally using this method, but I agree, it seems messy. However, I don't really think there's a better way around it. As long as I reassign and overwrite variables for 'result', and 'temperature', I should be OK for resources I suppose. This may end up being a massive operation with temperatures in different areas.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you run red.hmset you are overwriting the value of temperature. Given that you want to sort these values, you need to give each entry a unique identifier.

temperature:1, temperature:2 ...

You could then use the redis sort command

SORT mylist BY weight_* GET object_*

on the external keys.

Hope that helps in some way. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Is it possible to get a **subset** with hash? That is the problem I've been struggling with so far.